# buffered reader retrieves no values and premature end of file in a slightly different structured XML from same server

Tags: java, xml, bufferedreader

I have 2 XML files, one of which i currently retrieve from a remote source. The other XML structure is slightly different and causes the following error:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.
Oct 18, 2015 11:33:19 AM jtabs.Jtabs getdata1
SEVERE: null
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348)
    at jtabs.Jtabs.getdata1(Jtabs.java:576)
    at jtabs.Jtabs.access$000(Jtabs.java:43)
    at jtabs.Jtabs$1.run(Jtabs.java:452)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

The XML file which i CAN retrieve data from has the following structure:

```
<response>
<responseMetadata>
 <httpCode>200</httpCode>
 <errorType>Ok</errorType>
 <description>Success</description>
 <cappingApplied>No</cappingApplied>
 <cappingLimit>2000</cappingLimit>
 <queryString>EventStart=2015-08-11,EventEnd=2015-09-16,</queryString>
 </responseMetadata>
<responseBody>
 <dataItem>A</dataItem>
<responseList>
<item>
 <A>***</A>
 <B>***</B>
 <C>***</C>

etc etc
```

The XML file which i CANT retrieve data from has the following structure:

```
<response>
<responseMetadata>
 <httpCode>200</httpCode>
 <errorType>Ok</errorType>
 <description>Success</description>
 <cappingApplied>No</cappingApplied>
 <cappingLimit>500</cappingLimit>
 <queryString>FromDate=2015-10-18,ToDate=2015-10-19</queryString>
 </responseMetadata>
<responseHeader>
 <recordType>AA</recordType>
 <fileType>BB</fileType>
 </responseHeader>
<responseBody>
<responseList>
<item>
 <A>***</A>
 <B>***</B>
 <C>***</C>

etc etc
```

The way i retrieve the data of the working XML file is:

```
private static String callServer(String uri1, String params1) {
OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
BufferedReader br = null;
HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;
StringBuilder retVal1 = new StringBuilder();
try {
final URL url = new URL(uri1 + "?" + params1);
urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
urlConn.setDoInput(true);
urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
urlConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/xsl");
// Get the response
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
urlConn.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
retVal1.append(line).append("\n");
}
} catch (Exception e) {
throw new RuntimeException(e);
} finally {
try {
osw.close();
} catch (Exception ignore) {
}
try {
br.close();
} catch (Exception ignore) {
}
try {
urlConn.disconnect();
} catch (Exception ignore) {
}
}
return retVal1.toString();
}
```

However when i try and retrieve the data of the XML file using the same code above it appears to fail here:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
```

and causes the aforementioned error.

I have searched google for a few suggestions which include incorrectly formed XML, but using XML notepad the structure just appears slightly different as mentioned, could i get some help on this?

I have just run the following

```
int responseCode = urlConn.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
for (Entry<String, List<String>> header : urlConn.getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
System.out.println(header.getKey() + "=" + header.getValue());

}
```

which brings back some interesting results

the console displays

```
Response Code : 200
null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
Server=[nginx/1.6.0]
Content-Disposition=[null]
Connection=[keep-alive]
Content-Length=[0]
Date=[Sun, 18 Oct 2015 16:08:10 GMT]
Content-Type=[text/plain]
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.
Oct 18, 2015 5:08:07 PM jtabs.Jtabs getdata1
SEVERE: null
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:348)
    at jtabs.Jtabs.loadXMLFromString(Jtabs.java:300)
    at jtabs.Jtabs.getdata1(Jtabs.java:582)
    at jtabs.Jtabs.access$000(Jtabs.java:44)
    at jtabs.Jtabs$1.run(Jtabs.java:458)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

which shows there is 0 content length. Whilst if i run the same bit of code on the working XML i get a long number which is representative of data.

However if i put in the same non working url string into an XML notepad i see the items i want, and that there is data visible.

Help would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Solved- i overlooked that urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST"); should have been set to urlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");